# Google maps API v3 print page appears white line

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I created a page with google maps and I need to print it, but a white line appears in the map in some coordinates of the map, not all the locations it appears.

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqCrU.png)

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<title>Google Maps - Teste</title>

<!-- # CSS Imports # -->
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

<!-- # Javascript Imports # -->
<script src="js/site.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY_GOOGLEMAPS_API&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code (css/site.css):

```
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@media print {
  img {
    max-width: none !important;
  }
}
```

Javascript Code (js/site.js):

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: {
      lat: -27.6301719, 
      lng: -49.0330395
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
}
```

EDIT 1:

I found a solution ... Instead of taking a screenshot of the div in question, use the Google Maps Static API, where you send some parameters and it returns an image ... BUUUUUT see edit 2...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/?hl=pt-br

EDIT 2:

The URL of google maps static is limited by 8192 chars, and i need draw ALOOOOT lines into maps... so... im back to the init...

[## Sorry my bad english :(]

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or fiddle for the issue.

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Comment: @DanPhilip I tried to do this but I can not make the map appear on the fiddle ... Sorry :(